# how to Configure glide(for vendoring packages) for golang in windows

Tags: go

After making the project in Mac, I just want to configure it in windows

machine.For that how can i install glide in windows 8.1 for run go project.

-Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can download the Window's glide binary from their Github [releases page](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide/releases) and toss it under your path.

But you can always build it from source if you already got go installed.

1. Clone this repository into $GOPATH/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide and change directory into it
2. If you are using Go 1.5 ensure the environment variable GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT is set, for example by running export GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1. In Go 1.6 it is enabled by default and in Go 1.7 it is always enabled without the ability to turn it off.
3. go build -o glide -ldflags "-X main.version=$(git describe --tags)" glide.go

Comment: Got it.Thanks +1 :)

Comment: @ashvinpatel If it helped you, do you mind accepting it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

thanks @CESCO, i update it a bit, on window 10 64bit, you need to use  glide-v0.12.3, after downloaded it, extract and copy 'glide' to @GOPATH/bin